# order changed while using jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have fetched rows using query and applied datatable for the output table.
My query output is fetched as expected but while applying datatabe  to the table name 'approval' ,display order is changed. how to print thedisplay order as query fetched order.

```
var table=$('#approval').DataTable({                    
             dom: 'Blfrtip',
             "oLanguage": {
                  "oPaginate": {
                    "sPrevious": "<",
                    "sNext": ">"
                    }
                  },

                  "searching": false,
                  "iDisplayLength": 50


  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#approval').dataTable( {
  "ordering": false
} );
```

Please try this.
https://datatables.net/reference/option/ordering for your reference.

Otherwise it will take first column as sorting column.